# Make \leaders repeat a string at least a given number of times

Tags: glossaries, leaders

Using the *glossaries* and *glossary-longragged* packages (In a memoir document) as well as a custom style I found by Googling:

```
\newglossarystyle{dottedlocations}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}] 
            \emph{##3}\ignorespaces\unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill##5}%
            \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
     }
    \glossarystyle{dottedlocations}
```

([Source](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&p=59667))

My problem is that several of my abbreviations are used rather often, which makes the \leaders sometimes repeat the \hss. zero times, as demonstrated below for polydopamine:

[image]

I tried to insert a few dots manually before the \leaders, which lead to the appearance of a gap between those dots and the leaders. So the question is:
**Is there a way to force a \leaders to repeat a following \hbox a certain minimum of times?** i.e. is there a way to force the \leaders to repeat the \hbox at least three times before expanding if there is a need?

Comment: Just a remark on the code: `\ignorespaces` does exactly nothing. Its function is to expand the next token repeatedly until an unexpandable token remains; if it is a space it is gobbled and the procedure restarts from the next token, otherwise it stops. Since `\unskip` is unexpandable, the procedure stops immediately and nothing is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\leaders\hbox to2.9mm{\hss.\hss}\hskip 2.9mm plus1fill` instead your `\leaders` construction.

The `\hfill` is equivalent to `\hskip 0pt plus1fill` but you need to have some minimal space everywhere, such as `2.9mm` in my example.