# Leaders in tocloft with minimum width

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, leaders

How can I redefine the leader in `tocloft` so that it is has a minimum length? The background is that I always want leaders in TOC to appear with at least two dots, forcing line breaks in titles if necessary. The example below is a bit silly. The problem arises more often with multicolumn TOCs.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\cftsetpnumwidth{1em}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{Medium length title}
\section{Very, very long title of a section bbb bbb bb bb bb bb b b b b b b b}
\section{Medium length title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183528/make-leaders-repeat-a-string-at-least-a-given-number-of-times).

`\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\leaders\hbox to1em{\hss.\hss}\hskip 2.9mm plus1fill}` with `2.9mm` changed to desired minimum length.