# tikz -- using the remaining space of a line of text for squarepattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

For my math-lessons I'm searching for an easy way to fill the remaining space of a line with a squarepattern. There are some disadvantages with `leaders` (alignment, see [autofill with square-pattern (leaders vs. tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525527/autofill-with-square-pattern-leaders-vs-ti)), so I used the explanations in [Is there a way to measure the remaining space of a line of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}       

\newlength{\whatsleft}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page text area.east) in
    [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{floor((\x1-\x0)/#2)*#2}\global#1=#1}];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\mysquarefill}[4][r]{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}{#2}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{l}{}{\hfill}%
    \lower#4\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[step=5mm,color=gray](0,0) grid (\whatsleft,#3);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{c}{\hfill\mbox{}}{}%
}   


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\frac{8}{15} + \frac{7}{12}+ \frac{5}{12} +2=$\mysquarefill[l]{5mm}{10mm}{4mm}
\item $\frac{3}{4}$ von $ \frac{2}{5}=$\mysquarefill[r]{5mm}{15mm}{7mm}
\item $\frac{15}{28}\cdot\frac{14}{30}=$\mysquarefill[r]{5mm}{10mm}{4mm}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Now I'd like to simplify the code and especially combine the two macros. How do I use something like

```
\draw[step=5mm,color=gray](0,0) grid (floor((x-coordinate-of(current page text area.east) - x-coordinate-of(0,0))/#2)*#2,#3);
```

with `#2=size of squares` and `#3=height of squareblock`?

And is there an easier solution for the raggedleft/raggedright/center-mechanism?

Comment: You *can* use pgf functions in the coordinates. However, you will nevertheless need to make a measurement of the remaining distance because of the way `grid` works. If your aim is to do all of this in one command this can be done of course, but it won't make things *way* simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see what your actual question is.
(Why is @frougon's answer not satisfiable)
(You mentioned alignment. Of what? Horizontally or vertically?
Only you know what you want.)

Anyway, I propose the following construction
that uses Ti*k*Z to draw squares and uses `\leaders` to fill in spaces.
If you want to customize squares, play with Ti*k*Z.
If you want to align properly, play with TeX.
Have fun.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newbox\astackofsquares
\def\mysquarefill#1#2{
    \setbox\astackofsquares=\hbox{%
        \tikz[x=#1,y=#1,baseline=#1*#2/2-.5ex]{
            \path(0,0)(1,#1*#2);
            \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
                \draw foreach\i in{1,...,#2}{(0,\i-1)rectangle(1,\i)};
            \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        }%
    }
    \leaders\copy\astackofsquares\hfill\hbox{}
}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $\frac{8}{15}+\frac{7}{12}+\frac{5}{12} +2=$\mysquarefill{5mm}{2}
    \item $\frac{3}{4}$ von $\frac{2}{5}=$\mysquarefill{5mm}{3}
    \item $\frac{15}{28}\cdot\frac{14}{30}=$\mysquarefill{5mm}{4}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

### centered version

replace `\leaders` by `\cleaders`.

### flush left version

I propose using a clip instead of doing arithmetics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}\def\ShowFrameColor{\color{yellow}}

\begin{document}

\def\quarefillleft#1#2{
    \tikz[remember picture,x=#1,y=#1,baseline=#1*#2/2-.5ex]{
        \path(0,0)(0,#1*#2);
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \clip(-1,-1)rectangle(current page text area.north east);
            \draw(0,0)grid[step=#1](20cm,#2);
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    }
}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\frac{8}{15}+\frac{7}{12}+\frac{5}{12} +2=\quarefillleft{5mm}{2}$
    \item $\frac{3}{4}$ von $\frac{2}{5}=\quarefillleft{4mm}{3}$
    \item $\frac{15}{28}\cdot\frac{14}{30}=\quarefillleft{3mm}{4}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add the % in "...}%\leaders..." no extra-space is added. The first example-line shows the difference.

Comment: My question aimed at a solution, where the second example-line doesn't leave a big horizontal space between the "=" and the start of the squares. Additionally I wanted to have a solution with a flushleft / flushright-option for the squares.

Comment: @tern I add more variants. I highly recommend not to play with arithmetics. Let me know if you really want a flush right version.

Comment: Thank you for the approach with the clipping, that's a cool idea and the left-right-alignement of your version nice. The consequence of the clipping is, that the squares are cut off. That maybe ok for a lot of use-cases.